# Background Task with client.wait_for in multiple guilds

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a background task that I want to send to multiple guilds (but same channel name on each guild) and have each guild await for a button press. The code I wrote currently sends the background task to all guilds, but when I click the button, it sends a message to only one of the guild's channels, then makes the buttons in the other guild's channels not useable (basically stops the background task like it is finished).

I've messed with the indentation because I thought that is what was messing it up, but this format is the only way it will send to all 3 guilds and awaits for a button press. I'm clearly missing something here, should I add something to my check to fix this issue?

```
async def test_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed():
               
        components = [
                ActionRow(

                    Button(label='test',
                            custom_id='buttontest',
                            style=ButtonStyle.grey,
                            )
                            )]
    
        for guild in client.guilds:
            channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name='testchannel') 
            if channel:
                testmsg = await channel.send('click the button', components=components)
        try:
            def check(user):
                return user != client.user

            interaction= await client.wait_for('button_click', check=check, timeout = 360)
            
            if interaction.component.id == "buttontest":
                    await testmsg.delete()
                    await channel.send("test complete")
                        
        except discord.errors.HTTPException:
            pass
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            try:
                if testmsg is not None:
                    await testmsg.delete()
            except discord.NotFound:
                pass   

        await asyncio.sleep(int(30))

@client.event
async def on_ready():

    client.loop.create_task(test_loop())
```

Comment: You can't run them all in one coroutine - this will block all of the other ones. You need to separate each guild into its own function and then executing all of them at once.

Comment: @EricJin I figured out how to do that, but now it's sending the message for how many times the bot is in a guild (it's in 3 guilds so its sending the message 3 times in each guild)

Comment: Can you add that code to the question? I suspect it would be an extra loop or not updating the guild needed.